# How to decrypt an encrypted private key

Tags: wallet-recovery, raw-data, recover-private-key, base58, wallet-import-format

"addr": "193BiCSPG1fJzU4JSLhi4tvXUQ6Qr6kLiq",
"compressed": false,
"encrypted_privkey": "f567de89242dd72c66c9d47908928cd7c47df5dc5979f3af9787ce4d2a48380bd01562b4d2dbe2413d3f475fed02c491",
"pubkey": "0403704ed6f56af9f355f4aa45bd351699570ef6a33f31023f168be12e242614c8485c3c785f42efcd39d29b973b57ce8b32f15afacb0cfa55acb77722b0da6c8c",
"reserve": 1

i wanted to ask what is that encrypted private key , if its encrypted than how can i decrypt it

Comment: 1) which wallet software, 2) do you know the wallet password?

Comment: its from btc core dat file and well i dont know the passcode if i know that i think i can decrypt it through core wallet now what i did is i extract this data using pywallet codes now i have its encrypted M key salt now i am getting harder to decrypt private key hex if you know the answer i would really appreciate and like to learn.

Answer (score 1):

> **if its encrypted than how can i decrypt it**

If you know the password it can be decrypted.

If you don't know the password, you will not be able to decrypt it.

If you know almost all the password, a brute force search might succeed after a long time (weeks or centuries depending on how much you know)

> **its from btc core dat file**

There are a lot of fake wallets with names like "BTC core", If you mean "Bitcoin core" and have the genuine version, the following may apply:

There are password recovery tools that implement brute-force searching *if you know most of the wallet password*.

For example [BTCRecover](https://btcrecover.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) offers

> - Bitcoin wallet password recovery support for:
>
>   - Bitcoin Core

I havent tried this so this isn't a recommendation. I would expect there are many fake versions around that steal money.

You will soon also be contacted by criminals pretending to offer password recovery services. They will either steal your wallet contents or gain your confidence and trick you into paying invented fees.

Answer (score -1):

The encrypted private key you provided is a representation of the private key that has been encrypted using a specific encryption algorithm. To decrypt the encrypted private key and obtain the actual private key, you would need the corresponding decryption key or passphrase.

Without the decryption key or passphrase, it is not possible to decrypt the encrypted private key. Encryption is used to protect sensitive information, such as private keys, from unauthorized access. The encryption ensures that even if the encrypted private key is somehow obtained by someone, they would still need the decryption key or passphrase to decrypt and access the actual private key.

If you have the decryption key or passphrase associated with the encrypted private key, you can use the appropriate decryption algorithm or method to decrypt it and obtain the original private key. However, it is important to exercise caution and ensure that you are using a trusted and secure method to decrypt the private key, as mishandling or using insecure decryption methods can compromise the security of the private key and the associated funds.

If you are unsure about the encryption used or how to decrypt the private key, it is recommended to seek assistance from a knowledgeable and trusted source, such as the service or software provider that generated or provided the encrypted private key. They should be able to guide you through the decryption process and provide any necessary instructions or tools required for decryption.

Comment: Thankyou to all who recommend this but aside this what if we encode encrypted hex to base64 and try to change in WIF format is that possible to ???